# how to accepts list columns as Cassandra UDF parameter

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I created one table

```
CREATE TABLE human (chromosome text, position bigint,    
                    hg01583 frozen<set<text>>,
                    hg03006 frozen<set<text>>,
                    PRIMARY KEY (chromosome, position)
)
```

and i created function

```
CREATE FUNCTION process(sample list<frozen<set<text>>>)
CALLED ON NULL INPUT
RETURNS text
LANGUAGE java
AS 
$$


return leftsample==null?null:leftsample.getClass().toString()+" "+leftsample.toString();

    $$;
```

when i issie CQL query

> SELECT chromosome,position,hg01583, hg03006, process([hg01583,hg03006]) from human;

i got this error

```
SyntaxException: line 1:80 no viable alternative at input ',' ([[hg01583],..
```

how can i pass hg01583 ,hg03006 as list to process function?

Answer (score 0):

With each as own argument like: `SELECT chromosome, position, hg01583, hg03006, process(hg01583, hg03006) from human;`

```
CREATE FUNCTION process(hg01583 frozen<set<text>>, hg03006 frozen<set<text>>)
  CALLED ON NULL INPUT
  RETURNS text
  LANGUAGE java AS 
  $$
    return hg01583==null? null : ...
  $$;
```

If you want them to be dynamic, instead of creating fixed columns for each one make it a wide row and use a UDA to aggregate them with an accumulator function. like:

```
CREATE TABLE human (chromosome text, position bigint,    
                    sample text,
                    value frozen<set<text>>
                    PRIMARY KEY (chromosome, position, sample)
)
```

Comment: thanks for u r reply, but we can't create  process(sample list<frozen<set<text>>>) like that to accept dynamic number of column? , we have around 1000 column is thr, we need to choose around 5 to 6 column to pass to function.

Comment: `we have around 1000 column` your data model is wrong. If you make it so that 1000 rows are keyed by the sample (like above) vs 1 row with all 1000 you can use a UDA to dynamically do it with a IN query, but you cannot with current data model. ie `SELECT process(value) FROM human WHERE chromosome =  X AND position = Y AND sample IN ('hg01583', 'hg03006')`. Also a model with 1000 values per row is going to have worse performance since the driver cannot break it into chunks for more efficient paging.